# ZXING and LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, zxing

I am using LWUIT to develop ZXING application which stops taking video when video come across with a QR code.  I have seen j2me codes for zxing. Unforunately I found out that I cannot use some codes coz Canvas has been used a lot which LWUIT has no canvas.You have sample codes for LWUIT users to stop gettting video when camera saw a QRCode? I will be appreciated if you can provide me a sample code or tips for that. Thank you so much from now.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate zxing you need to connect the LWUIT MediaComponent (or VideoComponent in the latest version) to the zxing framework, I haven't done this myself though:
http://www.java.net/node/706015?force=786

The other approach is to show a native Canvas and go back to LWUIT when you are done by using Form.show() which automatically reinstalls the LWUIT canvas. This has the major drawback of not working on RIM devices.